# Capturing windows form into image

Tags: c#, capture

I know this question has been answered before. But none of the answers are correct.
How can I capture the image of a windows form and save it. I use this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
bmp.Save(@"C://Desktop//sample.png",ImageFormat.Png);
```

but get the error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

I have also read about this error but none of the suggestions work for me! Please help

Comment: are you sure you aren't just forgetting to dispose the bitmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in `bmp.Save(@"C://Desktop//sample.png",ImageFormat.Png);`.

First it must be @"C:\Desktop\sample.png", you don't need to escape anything with [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Second make sure the path is correct and you have permission to write to.

Third as Sayse point out dispose the bitmap.

```
using(Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
{
    this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
    bmp.Save(@"C:\Desktop\sample.png",ImageFormat.Png); // make sure path exists!
}
```

Comment: editting: it worked fine. Thank you. Please ignore the following

thank you. Actually that was my problem in the first place. How do I dispose the bitmap? by using bmp.Dispose? when I use this before the saving I get error. when I use it after saving I get the same GDI+ error

Comment: If anyone needs without border: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23187599/13701662

Answer (score 0):

Your path is in wrong format. Should be:

```
bmp.Save("C:\\Desktop\\sample.png",ImageFormat.Png);
```

What is more - check if the folder exists